# Confused about stdin stdout stderr?

Tags: unix, stdin, stderr

So I understand the meaning of the command such as `1>&2` or `2>&1` but
 my question is why do we use such commands? Redirecting the stdout to stderr or from stderr to stdout?

Also for  `$[$1 $sign $2]` command (used for simple calculator), is `$sign` a default command in Unix? What does it mean? What about the $ that is outside of the brackets?

Answer (score 2):

Two questions for the price of one.  It would be better asked as two questions since they are almost wholly unrelated.

#### I/O Redirection

- Why would you use `1>&2`?

  A standard reason is so a shell script reports errors on `stderr` instead of `stdout`.  For example:

  ```
  if [ ! -f "$file" ]
  then
      echo "$0: no such file - $file" >&2
      exit 1
  fi
  ```
- Why would you use `2>&1`?

  You want to capture all of the output from a command.  For example, you might be about to run a `find` command that will take ages, so you might write:

  ```
  find $HOME -name '*perq*' -print > log.file 2>&1 &
  ```

  All the data and error messages from `find` are sent to the `log.file` which you can study later when the command is complete.

#### The `[` (test) command

You ask about `$[$1 $sign $2]`.

This has so many problems it is difficult to answer coherently.  The question about a calculator suggests that maybe `$1` is supposed to be a number (let's use 13) and `$2` is too (let's use 9), and `$sign` might be either `+` or `-`.

- `$[` is not normally defined as a variable, so the shell will try to find a command `$[13` on the PATH and (normally) will fail.

  If you had written `[ $1 $sign $2 ]`, then we'd be better off.  There is a command `[` (also known as `test`).  It is usually a shell built-in, but originally was a separate executable (and you usually find that there is a `/usr/bin/test` (or `/bin/test`) and `/usr/bin/[` (or `/bin/[`) executable even on  modern systems.  Note that like all commands, the name (`[`) is separated from its arguments by spaces.  The `[` command requires the last argument to be `]`.  Now the expression might be:

  ```
  [ 13 + 9 ]
  [ 13 - 9 ]
  ```

  However, the `test` command would object; it doesn't support arithmetic.  It does support string comparisons `=` and `!=`; it supports numeric comparisons with `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt` or `-ge`.

If you want to do arithmetic, you either use the `expr` command, or one of the built-in alternatives:

```
x=$(($1 $sign $2))
```

This will assign 22 or 4 (depending on the value of `$sign`) to the variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

answer for redirection :

In unix the data/text file's are internally associated with something known as file handlers (integer's value) which help the OS distinguish and identify a file during processing. everything in unix is considered to be a file , even the input and output devices.

standard input is the keyboard , the standard output is stdout ie monitor which also functions as the stderr file stream , all this is by default
hence these are associated as file's hence have numbers assigned to them ....0 ,1 and 2.

so when you use something like 2>&1 you are basically telling the OS to put the stderr(2) data into the stdout(1) data stream

answer for $ sign :
the dollar sign here is a way to access the value of the variables.

example when you have a variable a like as below ::

```
Nitin@Kaizen > a=5 
Nitin@Kaizen > echo a --> will just print a 
Nitin@Kaizen > echo $a --> will print 5
```

note  : $a is same as ${a} or $[a] , they access the value of a variable .... kind of de-referencing

$[$1 $sign $2] :: you issue statement

```
Nitin@Kaizen > a=5
Nitin@Kaizen > b=3
Nitin@Kaizen > sign=+
Nitin@Kaizen > echo `expr $[ $a $sign $b ]`
    8   --- output is same as 5 + 3 , the value of a + b
```

answer for why you are confused :

you need make a slight effort to read a book completely again. these are very basics and hence become clear with a bit of programing and study.

Any good unix basic book would do that covers the chapters on File System (UFS) and a bit on scripting will do !!

hope this helps.